# How to navigate using h, j, k, l (Vi-like) in Xpdf?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xpdf

`man xpdf` says the following:

> Previous versions of xpdf included a "viKeys" X resource. It is no
>   longer available, but the following bindings are equivalent:
>
> ```
> bind h any scrollLeft(16)
> bind l any scrollRight(16)
> bind k any scrollUp(16)
> bind j any scrollDown(16)
> ```

But I am unable to use those keys for navigation. Do they work? Any special configuration required from my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured that out.
Go edit /etc/xpdf/xpdfrc and add the following

```
bind h any scrollLeft(16)
bind l any scrollRight(16)
bind k any scrollUp(16)
bind j any scrollDown(16)
```

Now, I have the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than adding those four lines to `/etc/xpdf/xpdfrc`
as suggested by [Senthil Kumaran's answer](https://superuser.com/a/46105),
I created a `~/.xpdfrc` file.

I'm French and I use a Dvorak bépo keyboard, so my `~/.xpdfrc` file includes:

```
bind c any scrollLeft(16)
bind r any scrollRight(16)
bind s any scrollUp(16)
bind t any scrollDown(16)
```